# Python sort tensor according to the diff between target and element

Tags: python, sorting, tensor, torch

suppose the original tensor is below

```
tensor([[0.9950, 0.6175, 0.1253, 1.3536],
        [0.1208, 0.4237, 1.1313, 0.9022],
        [1.1995, 0.0699, 0.4396, 0.8043]])
```

I want to sort the tensor according to the diff between 1 and the element, the element more closer to 1 will in front of the tensor, so the sorted tensor will be

```
sorted_tensor([[ 0.9950, 1.3536, 0.6175, 0.1253],
               [ 0.9022, 1.1313, 0.4237, 0.1208],
               [ 1.1995, 0.8043, 0.4396, 0.0699]])
```

is their any function provided bt torch? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this will work:

```
diffs_from_one = torch.abs(tensor - 1)
indices = torch.argsort(diffs_from_one)
sorted_tensor = tensor[indices]
```

Note I'm not super familiar with PyTorch specifically. But the general idea, using argsort to find the indices that should sort the original tensor for you, seems like the way to go.